# Casting find view by id is redundant

Tags: java, android

All elements (ImageView,TextView,Button) are yellow with some eror: "Casting find view by id is redundant", also XML.

When i start up app it just crashs. There is no red line, also I've tried with repair and build-> clean project. Doesn't help at all...

Please could you help me I have to finish this project till monday.

[java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YjFr.png)

[xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkVEJ.png)

Part of code:

```
private Button mButtonChoiceTrue;
private Button mButtonChoiceFalse;
mButtonChoiceTrue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTocno);
mButtonChoiceFalse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNetocno);
```

Crash Log:
`09-29 16:20:31.231 4814-4814/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-29 16:20:31.263 4814-4814/? I/zygote64: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false
09-29 16:20:31.292 4814-4814/? D/ActivityThread: ActivityThread,attachApplication
09-29 16:20:31.370 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/HwFLClassLoader: get used feature list :/feature/used-list failed!
    USE_FEATURE_LIST had not init! 
09-29 16:20:31.536 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
09-29 16:20:31.543 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
09-29 16:20:31.545 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
09-29 16:20:31.616 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustActivityImpl
09-29 16:20:31.617 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/HwCust: Create obj success use class android.app.HwCustActivityImpl
09-29 16:20:31.661 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz V/HwPolicyFactory: : success to get AllImpl object and return....
09-29 16:20:31.667 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
09-29 16:20:31.667 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/HwCust: Create obj success use class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
09-29 16:20:31.675 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz V/HwWidgetFactory: : successes to get AllImpl object and return....
09-29 16:20:31.685 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz V/ActivityThread: ActivityThread,callActivityOnCreate
09-29 16:20:31.808 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
09-29 16:20:31.809 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
09-29 16:20:31.810 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
09-29 16:20:31.811 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
09-29 16:20:31.878 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz W/Utils: Utils_isSuperResolutionSupport [load libai_client.so failed]
09-29 16:20:31.905 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/HwGalleryCacheManagerImpl: mIsEffect:false
09-29 16:20:31.924 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f0c0005, context : com.example.manue.rijekaquiz.RijekaQuiz@83de284, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
09-29 16:20:32.102 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
    CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
09-29 16:20:32.103 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
    CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
09-29 16:20:32.216 4814-4823/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=20KB, data=29KB
    After code cache collection, code=20KB, data=29KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
09-29 16:20:32.218 4814-4823/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=20KB, data=50KB
    After code cache collection, code=20KB, data=50KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
09-29 16:20:32.219 4814-4823/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 8MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
09-29 16:20:32.229 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
09-29 16:20:32.230 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
09-29 16:20:32.231 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
09-29 16:20:32.232 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
09-29 16:20:32.330 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-29 16:20:32.333 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.manue.rijekaquiz, PID: 4814
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.manue.rijekaquiz/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz.RijekaQuiz}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.manue.rijekaquiz.RijekaQuiz.startScreen1(RijekaQuiz.java:403)
        at com.example.manue.rijekaquiz.RijekaQuiz.updateQuestion(RijekaQuiz.java:252)
        at com.example.manue.rijekaquiz.RijekaQuiz.onCreate(RijekaQuiz.java:149)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
09-29 16:20:32.369 4814-4823/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=96KB, data=73KB
    After code cache collection, code=93KB, data=63KB
09-29 16:20:32.406 4814-4814/com.example.manue.rijekaquiz I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4814 SIG: 9`

Comment: The redundancy message is just a warning, it has nothing to do with the crash. You must add your crash log to the question. And please copy-paste it - don't add it as an image.

Comment: C:\AndroidQuiz-master\RijekaQuiz\app\src\main\java\com\example\manue\rijekaquiz\RijekaQuiz.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: That's not a crash log.

Comment: Btw. this code was working. Until one moment this all changed. There is no problem in initialisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RelativeLayout is null. Check out the lines in parentheses in your code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.manue.rijekaquiz.RijekaQuiz.startScreen1(RijekaQuiz.java:403)
    at com.example.manue.rijekaquiz.RijekaQuiz.updateQuestion(RijekaQuiz.java:252)
    at com.example.manue.rijekaquiz.RijekaQuiz.onCreate(RijekaQuiz.java:149)
```